# Removing join table data in sequelize returned value

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, associations

I am currently trying to remove a `joint` table data added when retrieving an association data.

The query is done by sequelize using a method added to the model through specifying model relationships(`sequelize magic methods`), for some reason, I'm not able to do that.

I have currently tried passing in `attributes: {exclude: ['...']}` to the method but the field still persists.

**Current association**

```
// Class sequelize model

Class.belongsToMany(models.Subject, { 
  through: 'ClassSubject', 
  foreignKey: 'class_id', 
  otherKey: 'subject_id', 
  as: 'subjects' 
})


// Subject sequelize model

Subject.belongsToMany(models.Class, { 
  through: 'ClassSubject', 
  foreignKey: 'subject_id', 
  otherKey: 'class_id',
  as: 'classes' 
});
```

**Query and Response**

```
const subjects = await dbClass.getSubjects(); // dbClass is a Class model instance

// Response
[
  {
    "id": "1b89d44c-2caa-452d-a1f8-7faa11970917",
    "name": "Mathematics",
    "code": "MATHS",
    "summary": "Mathematics for class 1",
    "ClassSubject": {
      "class_id": "637afc7b-40f6-478e-b35e-859ca462e2e7",
      "subject_id": "1b89d44c-2caa-452d-a1f8-7faa11970917"
    }
  }
]
```

**Desired output**

```
// Response
[
  {
    "id": "1b89d44c-2caa-452d-a1f8-7faa11970917",
    "name": "Mathematics",
    "code": "MATHS",
    "summary": "Mathematics for class 1"
  }
]
```

I have tried passing options to the method as specified below but to no avail

```
const subjects = await dbClass.getSubjects({ 
    attributes: { exclude: ['ClassSubject'] } 
});
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `joinTableAttributes` option and pass empty array to exclude everything in joint table.

```
const subjects = await dbClass.getSubjects({ joinTableAttributes: [] });
```

Comment: Ok, I would try that.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could upvote the 1st Answer, but that is indeed how to do it when lazy loading and using the .get method.

If you're trying to get rid of the join table information when eager loading you can use

```
dbClass.findAll({
  include: {
    model: dbStudent
    through: {
    attributes: []
    }
  }
})
```